Expect: ssh + sudo - How to get the exit code of the command?
I need to ssh + sudo and came up with this solution to know if the executed command failed.
But I did not manage to return the real retCode of the executed command, any idea ?
# ----------------------------------------------------
# connect to user@server & execute a command as root with sudo
# usage: f_ssh_sudo "server" "username" "password" "my_script.sh arg1 arg2"
function f_ssh_sudo() {
    local server=$1
    local username=$2
    local pw=$3
    local cmd=$4

    expect -f - <<-EOF
        set timeout 10
        spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${username}@${server}
        expect "*?assword:" { send -- "${pw}\n" }
        expect "*\$*"
        send -- "sudo ${cmd} && echo CMD_OK || echo CMD_FAIL\n"
        expect "*${username}*" { send -- "${pw}\r" }
        expect {
            "*CMD_OK*"   { send -- "exit\n" ; exit 0 }
            "*CMD_FAIL*" { send -- "exit\n" ; exit 1 }
        }
    EOF
    return $?
}

f_ssh_sudo 192.168.1.50 gandalf "Password1234" "ls -Alph /root"
echo "retCode=$?"


just like echo CMD_OK || echo CMD_FAIL, you can echo CMD_EXIT=$?, and then in upper level parse the CMD_EXIT= output.

The only thing you really need expect for here is to send the password, and that can be eliminated by using public-key authentication. The exit status of the remote command is the exit status of ssh itself.

Since you already appear to have unrestricted sudo privileges, you might as well configure sudo to allow execution without a password.
